# Example input for "paths" field in Phabricator Conduit API endpoint "diffusion.lastmodifiedquery"

Tags: phabricator

What input does the "paths" field on https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/diffusion.lastmodifiedquery/ accept? I've tried out various inputs such as `{"0":"file_path.py"}`, `{"0":"/<entire_directory_path>/file_path.py"}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
{ "paths": ["/<entire_directory_path>/file_path.py"] }
```

the key of the needed map is `paths` where its value is an array of paths.